# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 json_encode

Tags: php, ajax

I have looked through previous answers but i cant find anything.

I am using this to send my response;

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

From inspecting the result I am receiving this to the page in the Response;

```
    <br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &amp;quot;localhost&amp;quot; port 25, verify your &amp;quot;SMTP&amp;quot; and &amp;quot;smtp_port&amp;quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp64\www\ci7\php\MailSender.php on line <i>68</i></th></tr>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0018</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>377472</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\ci7\php\contact.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\contact.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0039</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>400616</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Apolo\MailSender->send(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\ci7\php\contact.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\contact.php<b>:</b>58</td></tr>
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>3</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0040</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>401224</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'><a href='http://www.php.net/function.mail' target='_new'>mail</a>
(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp64\www\ci7\php\MailSender.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\MailSender.php<b>:</b>68</td></tr>
</table></font>
{"status":"fail","errors":"Could not send a mail, sorry. Please try again."}
```

However, I get the error and i am not sure why?

This is the javascript;

```
        $.ajax({
        url: config.url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $form.serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            if(data.status && data.status == 'fail') {
                $.Apolo.modules.alertMessage({
                    target: $form,
                    type: 'error',
                    message: data.errors,
                    icon: 'warning'
                });
                $form.trigger('apolo.contactFormMessage');
                config.onError.call($form, data);
            }
            else if(data.status && data.status == 'success') {
                $.Apolo.modules.alertMessage({
                    target: $form,
                    type: 'success',
                    message: data.statusText,
                    icon: 'check'
                });
                $form.find('input, textarea').val('');
                $form.trigger('apolo.contactFormMessage');
                config.onSuccess.call($form, data);
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            $.Apolo.modules.alertMessage({
                target: $form,
                type: 'error',
                message: errorThrown,
                icon: 'warning'
            });
            $form.trigger('apolo.contactFormMessage');
            config.onError.call($form, arguments);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what's happening:

> https://www.kevinleary.net/syntax-error-unexpected-token-json-position-0/
>
> If you’re seeing a SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position
>   0 error in your browser console at angular.js:13920, or Line 13920 or
>   angular.min.js, then it’s likely that you’re working with HTTP API’s,
>   possibly using $resource or $http, and one of the API’s has an error
>   notice or warning in the response body.

In other words, the "response" you're getting is *NOT* JSON.  It's *HTML* - an HTML error message.  With a JSON string at the end.

You're doing the right thing - you have both `success: function(data)` and `error: function()` callbacks in your XHR request.

You need to:

1. Ensure that an "error" response from the server results in triggering the "error" callback in your Javascript, and/or
2. Detect when the server is sending a non-JSON response to either callback.

Comment: As per the above, the mail function was generating a PHP error which was being returned in HTML before the JSON response.  Suppressing the mail function error with '@' stopped the error prior to the response I required.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have solved the issue by adding @ in the mail function which removes the x-debug error and gives a clean response i.e.

```
            if(@!mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers)){

            $this->addError('Could not send a mail, sorry. Please try again.');
            return false;

        }
```

Comment: In other words, you've modifed your PHP back-end to suppress the PHP-generated HTML error text your Javascript front-end was gagging on: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php that

Comment: Exactly and as no PHP errors are returned, then you only receive the JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

Try parse object response:

```
var objData = JSON.parse(data);
```

or in Ajax

```
dataType: 'application/json'
```

or in server

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```